# creating trigger for Update other table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

as a school project i'm making an order and storage system. The server should add the newly arrived items to the storage when the status of an order is changed to received. How do i do this? what i came up with until now is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER statuswijzigen BEFORE UPDATE
ON `voorraadorder`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.Status = "ontvangen"
    THEN UPDATE `voorraadartikel`
    SET Voorraad = (SELECT voorraadartikel.Voorraad + voorraadordercontenct.Aantal 
                    FROM `voorraadartikel` AS v
                    INNER JOIN `vooorraadordercontent` AS r ON v.VoorraadArtikelID = r.ContentID
                    INNER JOIN `voorraadorder` AS o ON r.VoorraadOrderID = o.VoorraadOrderID 
                    WHERE v.VoorraadArtikelID = r.ContentID AND r.VoorraadOrderID = o.VoorraadOrderID);
END IF;
END
```

and the error i receive is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 11
```

all help is welcome :)

Comment: You need to define another delimiter like this `delimiter | create trigger ...`. If you don't set another delimiter than `;`, then the statement will end at the first `;` and your trigger definition will be incomplete. You need to tell *MySQL* that the statement should end at the delimiter you defined. After that you can set the delimiter back with `delimiter ;`

Comment: Are you asking about the logic of your task or about the syntax error you received?

Comment: Both. Why do i get the error, and is the logic correct